# What is the running time of Flann knn search in OPENCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, flann

What is the running time of `Flann knn` search in `OpenCV`?
I know that for index build, 
Linear index building will take `O(N*M)`, if I will find `q` points near to `M` points, where `M` points belong to `N` points. 
But I wonder the difference between the `index building` and `knn_search`.
Besides, why do we need to build the index???

Comment: You can think of the index building as a preprocessing step that organizes your data so as to make it possible to perform the KNN search quickly later on. The basic idea is that it "groups" the data points such that if you cannot find the KNN within some groups, there is no point in searching the other groups as they are bounding to be further away to your query point. This allows the algorithm to avoid doing a brute-force search over the entire dataset, which speeds things up. FLANN takes things further by employing randomization, which speeds up the process at the cost of accuracy.